# Transposing a table for use with gt::gt()

Tags: r, transpose, gt

I'd like to pipe `gt` at the end of this command but the function creates a list, which is not allowed in `gt()`

```
Error in UseMethod("group_vars"): no applicable method for 'group_vars' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"`

test <- datasets::attenu%>% map(function(x) (sum(is.na(x)))) 
test %<>% t(.)
```

I can do it if

```
datasets::attenu %>% map(function(x) (sum(is.na(x)))) %>% as_tibble() %>% gt::gt()
```

but then I can't transpose the table

```
test <- t(test)
```

at any point. Any suggestions about how to make the table vertical? Maybe the axis-flip is a "bug" that can be added to an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first `summarise` and get data in long format :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

datasets::attenu %>%
   summarise(across(.fns = ~sum(is.na(.)))) %>%
   #Or use summarise_all in older version of dplyr
   #summarise_all(~sum(is.na(.))) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
   gt::gt()
```

[image]